Amavis problem with quarantined email vanished
I've a postfix server with Amavis (v. 2.13.1).
When i receive a spam email...Amavis correctly block it but....email seems delivered but...discarded?!
This is the log of a message:
Apr  2 19:28:17 dfs01 amavis[2256237]: (2256237-12) Blocked SPAM {DiscardedOutbound,Quarantined}, MYNETS LOCAL [127.0.0.1]:54550 [95.110.216.5] <sender@pec.it> -> <manuel@localhost>, Queue-ID: ADA701200A2, Message-ID: <opec21023.2024
0402192647.84801.775.1.51@pec.aruba.it>, mail_id: 86Ik0z883qUa, Hits: 7.381, size: 25286, 4421 ms
Apr  2 19:28:17 dfs01 postfix/smtp[2259343]: ADA701200A2: to=<manuel@localhost>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=4.5, delays=0.05/0/0/4.4, dsn=2.7.0, status=sent (250 2.7.0 Ok, discarded, id=2256237-12 - spam)
Apr  2 19:28:17 dfs01 postfix/qmgr[971]: ADA701200A2: removed

1st question: these msg are lost?! :((
2nd: It's possible to setup Amavis to send spam email directly to spam user folder?!
Thanks in advance to all :)

I've setup Amavis conf file with:
$final_spam_destiny       = D_DISCARD;
$spam_quarantine_to       = "quarantine\@$mydomain";

